# How to add whole section to a bunch of html elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a section of class="box"  to the contents of the div id="primary", excluding the h1.  My html is below.

```
<div id="primary">

    <h1 class="page-title">Search Results for: dffd</h1>        

        <h2>Nothing Found</h2>
        <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>


 </div> <!--end #primary -->
```

So what I want to achieve is

```
<div id="primary">

  <h1 class="page-title">Search Results for: dffd</h1>  

 <section class="box">



        <h2>Nothing Found</h2>
        <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>

   </section>

 </div> <!--end #primary -->
```

**EDIT:  made a mistake, I don't want my h1 in the section, have amended question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#primary').children().not('h1').wrapAll('<section class="box"></section>');
```

Comment: Ah yes, `wrapAll`.  Good one.  I'll leave my answer intact but am upvoting yours.

Comment: brilliant function, had no idea it existed

Answer (score 4):

Use [jQuery's wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

```
$('#primary').wrapInner('<section class="box" />');
```

--**EDIT**--

Saw your revised question, try this:

```
// Wrap the contents in with the section
$('#primary').wrapInner('<section class="box" />');

// Detach (remove, but retain events/data) the <h1>, then prepend it to the primary div
$('#primay .box h1').detach().prependTo('#primary');
```

There are many ways you could do this, of course.

Cheers

Comment: thanks.  I made a mistake though!  Please see amended question, I don't want my H1 in the section.

Comment: if it's not possible, I can just add an empty div round the section I want

Comment: thanks would have marked yours as correct but since I have made my edit, the above now makes more sense.

Comment: I didn't downvote it just unmarked it as correct and marked above as correct instead